# Asynchronous Qt function run

Tags: c++

I'm new to Qt and to C++ programming, I've encountered an issue with asynchronous programming. I've connect the computer and an Arduino card but the problem is that the Arduino have a waiting time of 2 seconds while my UI is freeze. I know I need to call the function with `QtConcurrent::run()` but my function has a string argument. Here is what I've tried :

```
auto futureEnvoi =  QtConcurrent::run(envoie("debrancher"));
```

but the program return an error of build :

```
..\Menu\mainwindow.cpp: In member function 'void MainWindow::pourcentagebatterie()':
..\Menu\mainwindow.cpp:206:14: error: 'void futureEnvoi' has incomplete type
         auto futureEnvoi =  QtConcurrent::run(envoie("debrancher"));
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

and others in qfuture_impl.h and qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h

Comment: Read the documentation on how to pass arguments to a function you want to call: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#passing-arguments-to-the-function

Comment: already done but errors still there :/

Comment: Then you did not read it properly, because `QtConcurrent::run(envoie("debrancher"));` is most certainly not how the documentation explain you should do it

Comment: I know but when I try `QtConcurrent::run(envoie, string "debrancher");` I have also errors